# Xcode - Project References vs. copying .a file

Tags: xcode

I've been developing for iOS for over a year now, and in the last few projects, I've been using other projects, such as RestKit or SSZipArchive to name a few.  When doing these projects, I would include these projects as cross-referenced in the workspace underneath my main project.

What I find baffling about the process is that this is unlike any other language that I have encountered. Normally, in other languages, I take compiled output files from a project (.dlls or .jars, for example) and those are included in a project.  I know that when you build a static library in Xcode, the resulting file is a lib*.a file.

What is the reason for keeping these projects cross-referenced as opposed to just copying the lib*.a files into the project?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the reason for keeping these projects cross-referenced as
>   opposed to just copying the lib*.a files into the project?

Sounds like you're talking about adding the library project as a subproject. The reason for doing it is to set up a dependency between your project and the subproject. If changes are made to the subproject, Xcode will rebuild your main project so that the newest version of the library is incorporated.

Comment: For an established and stable library, you probably want to just add the output library file into your project. Keeps everything a little bit cleaner.

Comment: @Caleb kubi has the idea in mind that I'm talking about.  Is there any real reason to keep the library as a subproject when I won't make changes to that project.  I may update the project once I notice a feature or something gets added, but I'd much rather copy out a single file than have to worry about updating an entire project inside my project.

Comment: @DavidAndroidDev It's purely a convenience. You don't have to add the project if you don't want to. On the other hand, when you add a subproject to your project, it's really just a reference to some existing other project -- you don't "have to worry about updating an entire project inside \[your\] project." If you make changes to the library project, those changes will automatically be incorporated in whatever other projects have that library project as a subproject. But again, don't use it if you don't want it.